# ViewBag and ViewData are same..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I gave value to `ViewData` at Controller and I was able to retrieve the value with the help of `ViewBag` in View

```
ViewData["value"] = ViewBag.value
```

Please explain me briefly how!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to help, you need to post your code with a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

A `ViewBag` and `ViewData` will both last for one View.

ViewBags take magic strings with them, for instance:

```
ViewData["Foo"]
```

on the contrary to ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Foo
```

They both achieve the same goal, though.

Suggested read: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option)

They can both store simple and complex data (objects)

```
ViewBag.SimpleNumber = 42;
ViewData["MeaningOfLife"] = 42;

ViewBag.Text = "Some string";
ViewData["Text"] = "Some string";

MyObject myObj = new MyObject();

ViewBag.Object = myObj;
ViewData["Object"] = myObj;
```